# How would you go about creating RESTful services with multiple optional parameters using Spring

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, repository

I'd like to build a demo REST service that takes multiple optional parameters. Right now I have the code to take just one parameter, and if it's not present it gives an error.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/family")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Family> getMemberWithParams(@RequestParam("id") String rfamAcc) {
        return rfamRepository.findById(rfamAcc);
    }
```

So when you query this URL http://localhost:8080/family?id=RF00009 , you get the correct result given that the id is correct.
But what if I want to have multiple optional parameters? Do I have to write a function for every possibility or is there a simple solution? Do I have to hardcode the functions or can I just say something like:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/family")
        @ResponseBody
        public Optional<Family> getMemberWithParams(@RequestParam("id") String rfam_acc, @RequestParam("somethingElse") String somethingElse) {
            if(notPresent(rfam_acc)){
                return rfamRepository.findBySomethingElse(somethingElse); 
            return rfamRepository.findById(rfam_acc);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set 'required' property to false for `@RequestParam(required=false)` and set default value as well with 'defaultValue' property  `@RequestParam(value= fieldname, required=false, defaultValue="some default value")`

```
@PostMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(
          @RequestParam("name") String name,
          @RequestParam("price") Double price,
          @RequestParam(value ="title", required = false, defaultValue="Product Title") String title,
          @RequestParam(value = "dom", required = false) Date manufactureDate,
          @RequestParam(value = "images", required = false) List<MultipartFile> images) {
    //codes
        }
```